# java.awt.Robot does not work for handling "File Upload" dialog window when executed via Jenkins job

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, jenkins

Robot class does not work when the selenium suite is executed via a Jenkins job. The same suite however works successfully when executed on local machine.

Need answers for following:

1. Is there any Jenkins plugin or config changes required for Robot class to work on Jenkins ( basically am I missing anything? )
2. Is there any approach that can be leveraged for handling "File Upload" dialog that will run successfully when executed via Jenkins job ?
3. As far as I have searched Robot Class, AutoIt and Sikuli are the 3 approaches for handling Window's dialog popup but which of these is compatible with Jenkins as well ?

Comment: can you view the test cases runing or it's a headless browser?

Comment: I am running via Jenkins job and I can't see them in execution like when I do when running via Eclipse. (so it seems its headless)
But when I embedded following script to check if its headless: 

System.out.println("Is Headless = " + GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()); 

I get following output: 
Is Headless = false

Comment: Yes, it seems to be headless, that's the only reason you cannot see the execution and that the reason for robot commands to not work. There are ways to see the execution on real browser with jenkin. You can only use robot classes on real browsers.

Comment: You need to keep the PC/Server unlocked for the file upload dialog to work.

Comment: Keshav is right. Robot framework work with visible area of screen or monitor. Use real system instead of headless browser.

Comment: is there any solution for the above question?
i am facing the same issue.
tried both robot and AutoIt none is working when executing my scripts with jenkins.